# Xubuntu Alt+Tab behavior

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, xfce, window-manager

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04 and I want to change the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> behavior. In Xubuntu, it just has the option to alternate between applications, but I prefer something like Gnome Shell or Unity, that have the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to change between windows of the same instance. This is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found that option among commands that you can assign the shortcut to in *Window Manager Settings* via *Whisker menu → Window Manager → Keyboard → Switching between windows of the same program*. (Translation mine, so official one may vary.)

In my case it's <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, but I think it was empty by default.